# MiKTeX package schemes and collections

Tags: miktex

I'm very new to all things TeX/LaTeX and having a recuring kind of issue: with the widespreading of TeX Live distribution, guides and tutorials all around the Web very often refers to TeX Live collections in their install/setup sections, mainly the `latex-extra` and `latexmk` ones.

I've looked into the docs and searched for informations about how to get a similar install with MiKTeX, to no avail.

As MiKTeX is the recommended way for Windows users and handily available using Winget, I'd gladly use it for the Sphinx docs I'm updating (namely, Nextcloud).

Thanks in advance for your insights
TY
J

Comment: Texlive works perfectly fine on windows. I would use texlive instead of miktex. Packages are usually updated a bit faster in texlive and it seems to have less packaging errors. And as you've notices, texlive is used by a lot of people, so getting help is usually much easier.

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple different sites you should include links to all other versions of your question in every question!

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/75825818/2777074

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you for your prompt answer as well as for the cross posting advice (will try to avoid it anyway)

Comment: your question isn't very clear, choice between miktex or texlive on windows is fairly arbitrary, use either, but if you want one that is packaged like texlive, use texlive.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's most probably because I was indeed looking for clarification! :)
I wondered if MiKTeX had similar "meta-packages" like TL's schemes and collections, as they ease installation of standardized lists of packages. For example, Sphinx-doc users only have to install TL, latex-extra and latexmk to be able to build their documentation as PDFs.
OTOH, MiKTeX being available with a simple `winget install miktex` makes it straightforward to get TeX/LaTeX installed on a Windows computer.
I hoped one could get the best of both distributions. Looks like I can't…

Comment: … Another reason (as if one were still needed!) to use Chocolatey, which brings everything in one single command:

`choco install texlive --params="'/collections:latexextra /extraPackages:latexmk'"`